# How prevent chef failure on ruby code?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, recipe

Sometimes Chef fails on the next code (this code not in block or any resource):

```
tmp = title.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("UTF-8")
title = tmp.encode('ISO8859-1').force_encoding('UTF-8')
```

error that I get:

### NoMethodError

undefined method `force_encoding' for nil:NilClass

My question is how best practice to ignore any code error and to continue to run rest recipes, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show where `title` comes from so they best I can say is to put your code in a `ruby_block` resource and use the `ignore_failure` property. You can also use normal Ruby `rescue` blocks for imperative code but be aware of how that interacts (or rather, doesn't) with resources, see https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ for some details on the loading process Chef uses.